# How to redirect 404 not found page to the home page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, http-status-code-404, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a 404 error page which I don't want to use. Instead, I want to have the 404 page reload to my home page. I inserted the lines below in the beginning of the 404 php file:

```
<?php
/* Redirect browser */

echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
      </script>';

/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
?>
```

This works (it will load to my homepage. However, the new page will reload and a new tab page will open.

I want to have the page reload and NOT to open a new tab.

How can I do this?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`is_404`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_404/) function and hook it in the [`template_redirect`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) hook. If it returns true you could use [`wp_safe_redirect`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/) function to redirect to the home/front page.

```php
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirecting_404_to_home');

function redirecting_404_to_home()
{
    if (is_404()) 
    {
        wp_safe_redirect(site_url());
        exit();
    }
};
```

Code goes onto the `functions.php` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however there is still a tab opening. Should I have used a specific name for the 404 page torso?

Comment: No it does **NOT** open a new tab on my end! The code I gave you has been tested and works fine and has nothing to do with opening a new tab on your browser! It could be a theme related issue, or even a browser setting issue. So 1- which theme you're using? 2- Which browser you're using?

Comment: that is strange.....I am using the salient theme in both safari and firefox. What are all lines your using?

Comment: If you've tested it on multiple browsers and it still opens up a new tab, then I'd say it's a theme related issue. The code I provided you with, has nothing to do with opening a new tab on a browser. I've used it on all of my websites for many years without any issue!

Comment: I just searched for your theme issue and found this: [There is a known issue with the Salient WordPress theme where it causes links to be opened as a new page in the theme](https://smashballoon.com/doc/fixing-the-salient-theme-conflict/). It says go to `Salient Theme Options -> Page Transition, and then uncheck “Disable Fade Out On Click”.`

Comment: Yes I see. I did what the page said, only the weird thing keeps happening :/